# Stastistical summary of data group by Cut

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, cut

I have hundreds of data providing body weight of small animals at various ages obtained from multiple research papers.  I want to group and analyse the weight by age for periods of 7d.  I have used cut in R successfuly to group the data by age and have the default number of values (count) in each 7d bin.  But even after much Googling I can't find a means to extend 'cut' to obtain basic statistical summaries for each age bin to include mean, SE, CL and median.  Is that possible and can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

I also looked at dplyr and although that seems to have the capability to provide statistical summaries, I couldn't see a way of grouping the ages by 7d intervals. Would that be a better alternative?

Thank you for any assistance from a non-programmer.

Additional info

Thanks to both of you for your comments.  I am sorry to have provided limited information,  I hope this clarifies the problem.  I have over 2000 rows of data in Excel.  The rows are age in days and the columns are 'MaleFI', MaleMEI' and MaleBW where FI is food intake, MEI is metabolizable energy intake, and BW is body weight.  A section of the data is shown below.  Usually I can analyse the data with an Excel Pivot Table but that does not include an option to calculate median or standard error;  Power Pivot does but doesn't group!  So the data are as follows (sorted by age in days and no blanks):

- Age   Male FI  MaleMEI  Male BW
- 28.00  14.62  212.66  121.68
- 28.00  13.82  201.03  112.15
- 28.00  13.82  201.03  112.15
- 29.00  15.12  220.31  125.14 ...

The ages are continous and may go up to about 900, with a varying number of values for each age.

The objective is to group by 7d periods and as I mention have statistical analysis on each group thus:

- Age  MaleFI   MaleMEI   MaleBW
- 21-28  Mean   Mean Mean
- SE     SE  SE
- Median Median  Median
- 29-35  Mean   Mean  Mean
- SE     SE  SE
- Median Median  Median
- 36-42 etc.

This is the code that I used to group the data, but as I mentioned, with hindsight probably using dplyr with group_by and summarise might be a better approach.

```
library("xlsx")
library("dplyr")
Pivot.data <- read.xlsx(file.choose(), 1)  # read first sheet
pt<-cut(Pivot.data$Age, breaks=seq(21, 800, by=7))
table(pt)
```

The output is 
(21,28]   (28,35]   (35,42]   (42,49]   (49,56]   (56,63]   (63,70]   (70,77]
   6        15        41        73        92        98        95        99

I would be happy with the format of the ranges, i.e (21,28] etc rather than 21-28.

Thanks for your comments and I am sorry not to have made the requirement clearer.  I do appreciate you giving up your time to help.

Dan,  here is the output using dput:

> dput(head(Pivot.data, 20))
>   structure(list(Age = c(28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 30, 35, 35, 35, 
>   35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35), MaleFI = c(14.62, 13.82, 
>   10.6691449814126, 15.9859154929577, 11.7, 14.0273778252258, 13.5877862595419, 
>   17.73, 17.93, 17.99, 22.1214285714286, 17.6, 22.48, 21.7, 19.6, 
>   21.4, 21.25, 20.37, 19.3215613382899, 23.169014084507), MaleMEI = c(212.66252, 
>   201.02572, 144.342862453531, 216.273450704225, 160.171462269, 
>   204.047711328562, 197.653240885495, 257.90058, 241.76812, 261.68254, 
>   298.285342857143, 238.3216, 304.40168, 315.6482, 285.1016, 311.2844, 
>   309.1025, 296.30202, 261.401403345724, 313.453591549295), MaleBW = c(121.68, 
>   112.15, 85.7142857142856, 143.181818181818, 109.20245398773, 
>   89.8187948576385, 126.522593320235, 131.96, 127.98, 142.57, 126.92, 
>   146.9, 145.45, 131.9, 129.8, 132.4, 191.21, 179.44, 138.095238095238, 
>   202.272727272727)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. For us to help you, you need to share a reproducible example with us: a code that we can run which reproduce your dataset and an expected output. In R, you may use `dput(head(your_df, 20))` and post the result in your question.

Comment: I hope the edit above shows the requirement more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it is not that yet. You didn't use `dput` as I suggested so your code can only be used by you, which is not very helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly (but please, try to include a reproducible example next time), this code should do:

```
library(tidyverse)
your_df %>% 
  # mutate(Age_cl = cut(Age, c(-Inf,30,60,Inf))) %>% 
  mutate(Age_cl = cut(Age, breaks=c(-Inf, seq(min(Age), max(Age), by=7), Inf), right = F)) %>%
  group_by(Age_cl) %>% 
  summarise(
    n=n(),
    m=mean(Age, na.rm=T),
    sd=sd(Age, na.rm=T),
    max=max(Age, na.rm=T),
    min=min(Age, na.rm=T)
  )
```

You create the new column `age_cl` which is the result of `cut`, then you group by this new column and `summarise` (or you could `mutate` again, as you want) all the summaries you want.

You can also use `summarise_at` with a list of functions:

```
your_df %>% 
  mutate(Age_cl = cut(Age, c(-Inf,30,60,Inf))) %>% 
  group_by(Age_cl) %>% 
  summarise_at("Age", list(m=mean, sd=sd, max=max, min=min), na.rm=T)
```

Note that the other arguments will apply to all functions, like `na.rm` here.

**EDIT:** For the records, it seems that there is a way to use the `summary` function, but you have to transform its results into a data.frame for it to work. This may not be worth it for `summary`, compared to writing your functions like above. Here is an example with the `iris` dataset:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Sepal.Length_cl = cut(Sepal.Length, c(-Inf,5,6,Inf))) %>% 
  group_by(Sepal.Length_cl) %>% 
  group_modify(~summary(.$Sepal.Length) %>% unclass %>% t %>% as.data.frame)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I will have a try with your suggestion.

Comment: I used the original code exactly as you suggested but with my actual df name.  I received following error: Error: Column `age_cl` must be length 1996 (the number of rows) or one, not 13. The 1996 matches the number of data rows in the imported Excel sheet.

Comment: @GrahamTobin I corrected `age` to `Age`, and it worked on your `dput` output. Try again :-)

Comment: Almost brilliant!  I made the change above but problem still existed.  I had an error message that Tidyverse was using an old version of rlang.  'Updating' rlang produced the same error message.  I manually deleted all the libraries (I should have tried just rlang).  Installed latest version of rlang package, followed by tidyverse package.  The code worked perfectly.  I have extended the summarise section to include MaleFI, MaleMEI, MaleBW and median.  Perfect and values match Excel pivot table.  I have manually added part of the age ranges that I needed and that works too.  One issue yet.

Comment: Dan, should I paste the current solution as an edit to the original question?  Haven't seen anything like it elsewhere.  Now for the gold star!  I can manually paste in the age ranges to compute i.e.c(21,28,35, 42, etc) but it would be much more elegant to use a code that set a minimum and maximum for the range (21, 900) and the interval (7).  Something like 'breaks=seq(21, 800, by=7)'.

Comment: @GrahamTobin Sorry but I didn't understand your last problem. You should not copy the solution in your question, but just upvote the answer if you think it was good and mark it as "accepted" if you think your question is solved. I edited my answer to include your breaks with min and max age.

Comment: Dan, I very much appreciate your efforts and patience.  I now have the program that I need to analyse my data per my original goal.  My suggestion was simply so that others would see a complete code flow from importing their original Excel sheet to the full analysis.  I still haven't found an example on line of the code that you suggested to break the data down into fixed intervals.  Most seem to group by a name rather than numerical values.  Best regards.